# Find the range of the following function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the range of the following function:

$$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x^2-5x-6}$$

I know how to find the domain only

Please provide an explanation.

EDIT: Another question: find the range of

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)(5-x)}$$

How would we do that?

Comment: Range should be $(-\infty,\infty)$. Apply what you have been taught in the class.

Comment: Don't add new questions to old ones. Instead, upvote/choose answers that helped you here and ask a new question **if** you get stuck after checking carefully the answers to this question, which undoubtedly can help you with then new question.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\;r\in\Bbb R\;$ , so we want to check when

$$\frac{x-1}{x^2-5x-6}=r\iff rx^2-(5r+1)x+1-6r=0$$

The above quadratic's discriminant is :

$$\Delta=25r^2+10r+1+24r^2-4r=49r^2+6r+1$$

and certainly $\;49r^2+6r+1>0\;,\;\;\forall\;r\in\Bbb R\;$ (why? Look again at this new quadratic's discriminant)  and from here that the quadratic's a solution for *any* $\;r\in\Bbb R\;$ , and thus the function is onto (or what's the same: the range is $\;\Bbb R\;$ )

Answer (score 1):

the range of $f(x) = \dfrac{x-1}{(x+1)(x-6)}$ is $(-\infty, \infty).$ here is the reason. show that $\lim_{x \to -1+}f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 6-} f(x)= -\infty$ and $f$ is continuous in $(-1, 6).$  these three conditions imply the conclusion that the range of $f$ is $(-\infty, \infty).$

Answer (score 1):

From partial fractions decomposition,
$$\frac{x-1}{x^2-5x-6}=\frac{x-1}{(x+1)(x-6)} =\frac{2}{7(x+1)}+\frac{5}{7(x-6)}.$$
Both fractions are decreasing continuous functions on the domain: $(-\infty,-1)\cup (-1,6)\cup (6,+\infty)$.

In particular, it is continuous decreasing on $(-1,6)$. On another hand, $$\lim_{x\to -1_+}f(x)=+\infty, \quad\lim_{x\to 6_-}f(x)=-\infty, $$
Hence, by the intermediate value theorem, the range of $f$ is $(-\infty,+\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

If we factor, we have $\dfrac{x-1}{(x+1)(x-6)}$, and since there are no holes in the graph of the function. There is a horizontal asymptote at $y=0$, but this function has a zero at $x=1$, and thus the value $y=0$ is reached. Therefore the function has range $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @RainiervanEs Right, local behavior versus global.

Comment: but when x = 6, then there's a hole

Answer (score 0):

> **Pure Algebraic Way of Doing This Without any Graphic Calculator**

Let y = $\frac{x-1}{x^2-5x-6}$

**Using Cross Multiplication**

x$^{2}$y -x$\left(5y+1\right)$-6y+1=0$\Longrightarrow$x=$\frac{\left(5y+1\right)\pm\sqrt{\left\{ 5y+1\right\} ^{2}-4y\left(1-6y\right)}}{2y}$
$\Longrightarrow$$\left\{ 5y+1\right\} ^{2}-4y\left(1-6y\right)$>
0

=$\left\{ 5y+1\right\} ^{2}-4y\left(1-6y\right)$= $\left(7y+\frac{3}{7}\right)^{2}+\frac{40}{49}$>0

which is always true $\forall$ y $\in.$$\mathbb{R}$

> **Hence the Range** is= $\mathbb{R}$